# jqGrid issues: saveRow - explanation

Tags: jqgrid, save, row

Please, can someone explain me how saveRow works to save the data in database? How is it possible? Do I have to do some code in ajax, or something like that?

I already read the documentation and I really didn't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jqGrid would allows you to perform CRUD operations.  All of these operations if they are going to operate against a database would then send information back to the server with information about the record that is being created, updated, deleted.  Your server side of things would then have to translate that into the actions that would translate that to your database.

jqGrid will not do all of this for you, it is just a front end. There will almost for sure be tutorials on how to do some of these basic operation on whatever technology stack you choose to use.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mark, I was thinking that jqGrid handle this for me... so the saveRow, editRow and other functions just do the client-side? And for example, to update a row in a database I'm using php in the server-side, where do I have to put the functions? I know I'm doing so many questions and bothering you but I really didn't understand this and I spend a couple of days searching this things on google and I didn't get it :(

Comment: @mzs_newbie: jqGrid is pure JavaScript solution. So it can have no direct access to the database or to any resource existing on the server. So it send just the values of all columns having `editable: true` option plus `id` (id of edited rows) and the parameter `oper` with one from the values: `add`, `edit` or `del`. The server have to read the information and to perform CRUD operations in the database.

Comment: Huummm thank you so much for reply@Oleg. Your explanations are so good :) I'm sorry but I have another doubt... I think I did this in my code but it is not working :( I put `editable:true` in the columns. And I made a file for the server-side to handle with the data where I put some conditions like `if ($_POST['oper'] == 'add') { //insert it on database }` and the other functions for CRUD, but this is not working. Do I have to have "something special" to read the information ahd perform CRUD operations?

Comment: @mzs_newbie: First of all I would recommend you to *localize* the origin of your problem. If you don't used [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Network tab of Developer Tools of IE or Google Chrome before you should start usage now. You will see full HTTP traffic. You will see exactly in which form the data will be send to the server and returned back. I don't use PHP so I can't help you in your PHP code.

Comment: Hummm ok. Thanks again @Oleg. I will do this :)
Thanks for your time and your help ;)

Comment: @mzs_newbie: You are welcome! It's really important to see HTTP traffic. It helps to see what's happens really: what will be send. If you don't see that required information are sent then you should debug JavaScript code. If information will do send, but you don't see it in PHP code you should examine PHP code or configuration of PHP server to find the reason. I personally use mostly [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp), but it's mostly the matter of the taste.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D Yeah it's very difficult and I'm not used to use these tools but now I'm going to start it! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Oleg now my grid is working... I tested it with firebug... I had done everything right, I just was confused, because it wasn't working but my problem was with the sql, I was doing this in the wrong form. Thanks again @Oleg!

Comment: @mzs_newbie: You are welcome! Tracing of HTTP traffic is mostly important to be sure on which side you should search for the error. If you see in HTTP that the parameters were correctly send to the server then you can concentrate your later investigation of the back-end (your PHP code, SQL statements and so on). In any way, it's good to know that the problem is solved now. Best wishes!

Comment: Thank you :D Best wishes for you too ;)